# logistic regression model with L1 regularisations

Tags: python, pytorch, logistic-regression, regularized

I am trying to apply L1 regularization on a logistic model

```
class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(-1, 784)
        output = self.linear(x)
        return output

    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        output = self(images)                 
        loss = F.cross_entropy(output, labels)
    
    
        acc = accuracy(output, labels)           
        return {'Training_loss': loss, 'Training_acc': acc}
      
    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        batch_losses = [x['Training_loss'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   
        batch_accs = [x['Training_acc'] for x in outputs]
        epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()     
        return {'Training_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'Training_acc': epoch_acc.item()}

    def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
        print("Epoch [{}], Training_loss: {:.4f}, Training_acc: {:.4f}".format(epoch, result['Training_loss'], result['Training_acc']))
model = LogisticRegression()
```

But I think I am doing it wrong the accuracy did not change.

```
L1=0.2
def evaluate(model_b, trainloader):
    outputs = [model_b.training_step(batch) for batch in trainloader]
    return model_b.training_epoch_end(outputs)

def fit(epochs, lr, model_b, trainloader, opt_func=torch.optim.SGD):
    history = []
    optimizer = opt_func(model_b.parameters(), lr)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        ##### Training Phase 
        for batch in trainloader:
            loss = model_b.training_step(batch)['Training_loss']
            
            loss_Lasso = loss  + 0.5 * L1 #  L1 reg
            
            loss_Lasso.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        result = evaluate_b(model_b, trainloader)
        model_b.epoch_end(epoch, result)
        history.append(result)
    return history
```

Can anyone help me with what I am missing and how I can really apply  L1 regularization?
Also, is  L1 regularization called lasso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the *l1-norm* is a type of Lasso regularization, yes, but [there are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Generalizations).

In your snippet `L1` is set as a constant, instead you should measure the *l1-norm* of your model's parameters. Then sum it with your network's loss, as you did. In your example there is a single layer, so you will only need `self.linear`'s parameters. First gather all parameters then measure the total norm with [`torch.norm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.norm.html). You could also use [`nn.L1Loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.L1Loss.html).

```
params = torch.cat([x.view(-1) for x in model.linear.parameters()])
L1 = lamb*torch.norm(params, p=1)
```

Where `lamb` is your *lambda* regularization parameter and `model` is initialized from the `LogisticRegression` class.

Comment: for lambda what are the possible values? I know that it reduces the overfitting but increases the bais am I right?

Comment: Before applying L1 the accuracy was around 80 after applying the above code it drops to 12 !! is that possible or It means that I am doing it wrong???

Comment: You probably have a lambda factor that is too high. Having it too high will ruin your model's performance. It is a hyper-parameter of your model, so you will have to tweak it. And yes it can prevent over-fitting and it seems you're right about [increased bias](https://towardsdatascience.com/regularization-the-path-to-bias-variance-trade-off-b7a7088b4577).

Comment: I tried 0.2 but still very low accuracy, just to make sure the loss function insid the fit method will be  
loss_Lasso = loss  + L1 #  L1 reg
true?

Comment: Is your model overfitting without the regularization?

Comment: I am a beginner in the field of ML, however the accuracy of my model on the training set is 85 and on the testing is 83, I would like to explore the effect of L1 and understand overfitting more. 
Appreciating your passion and efforts

Comment: I see, it's usually good to plot both losses over epochs. This allows you to get an idea of how well/bad the validation loss evolves compared to the training loss. If at some point, the validation loss starts increasing or stalls out, while the train loss is decreasing (here I mean lower=better). It would indicate you are overfitting your model. Then you would look into adding regularization to your training: loss regularization is one of them but **there are others** (smaller model, bigger dataset, data augmentation, dropouts, weight decay, lower input size, lower batch size, ...).

Comment: Thaaaaanks for your great help !